# How to handle web api by flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am using Nginx+uWSGI+Flask to build up a web service API.

I follow http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/uwsgi/ as below

In Nginx, I want Flask handle all request appapi, and others handle by nginx.

ex.
    http://www.example.com/appapi/query?name=123 will be handled by flask
    http://www.example.com/ will be handled by nginx.

I add below configuration to let flask handle.

```
location = /appapi { rewrite ^ /appapi /; }
location /appapi { try_files $uri @appapi ; }
location @appapi {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /appapi;
  uwsgi_modifier1 30;
  uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3301;
}
```

uWSGI has listen 3301 port, and will load flask app, In Flask app code. I have defined route for appapi

```
@app.route('/appapi/query', methods=['GET'])
def query():
    print 'query()'
```

But I find query function is not called, and in log. it return 404, not found.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@app.route('/query', methods=['GET'])
def query():
    print 'query()'
```

Then in the Nginx config:

```
location /appapi/ {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3301;
}
```

Comment: It seems works, Thanks, I have a more question, why document (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/uwsgi/) use uwsgi_modifier1 and uwsgi_param and why it not work?

Comment: `uwsgi_modifier1` is deprecated. `uwsgi_param` passes the script name, but it's simpler to just use routes based on `/`

Comment: yes, I use / routes, it works fine, then I want to only route api to flask and others handle by nginx, but I encounter the problem asked in post.